# Is it possible to match the "next" unmatched record in a SQL query where there is no strictly unique common field between tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Using Access 2010 and its version of SQL, I am trying to find a way to relate two tables in a query where  I do not have strict, unique values in each table, using concatenated fields that are mostly unique, then matching each unmatched next record (measured by a date field or the record id) in each table.

My business receives checks that we do not cash ourselves, but rather forward to a client for processing.  I am trying to build a query that will match the checks that we forward to the client with a static report that we receive from the client indicating when checks were cashed.  I have no control over what the client reports back to us.

When we receive a check, we record the name of the payor, the date that we received the check, the client's account number, the amount of the check, and some other details in a table called "Checks".  We add a matching field which comes as close as we can get to a unique identifier to match against the client reports (more on that in a minute).

```
Checks:

ID    Name    Acct    Amt    Our_Date      Match
__    ____    ____    ____    _____        ______
1    Dave     1001    10.51   2/14/14     1001*10.51
2    Joe      1002    12.14   2/28/14     1002*12.14
3    Sam      1003    50.00   3/01/14     1003*50.00
4    Sam      1003    50.00   4/01/14     1003*50.00
5    Sam      1003    50.00   5/01/14     1003*50.00
```

The client does not report back to us the date that WE received the check, the check number, or anything else useful for making unique matches. They report the name, account number, amount, and the date of deposit.  The client's report comes weekly.  We take that weekly report and append the records to make a second table out of it.

```
Return:

ID    Name    Acct    Amt    Their_Date      Unique1
__    ____    ____    ____    _____        ______
355    Dave   1001    10.51    3/25/14     1001*10.51
378    Joe    1002    12.14    4/04/14     1002*12.14
433    Sam    1003    50.00    3/08/14     1003*50.00
599    Sam    1003    50.00    5/11/14     1003*50.00
```

Instead of giving us back the date we received the check, we get back the date that they processed it.  There is no way to make a rule to compare the two dates, because the deposit dates vary wildly.  So the closest thing I can get for a unique identifier is a concatenated field of the account number and the amount.

I am trying to match the records on these two tables so that I know when the checks we forward get deposited.  If I do a simple join using the two concatenated fields, it works most of the time, but we run into a problem with payors like Sam, above, who is making regular monthly payments of the same amount. In a simple join, if one of Sam's payments appears in the Return table, it matches to all of the records in the Checks table.

To limit that behavior and match the first Sam entry on the Return table to the first Sam entry on the Checks table, I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT return.*, checks.*
FROM return, checks
WHERE (( ( checks.id ) = (SELECT TOP 1 id 
                       FROM   checks 
                       WHERE  match = return.unique1 
                       ORDER  BY [our_date]) ));
```

This works when there is only one of Sam's records in the Return table.  The problem comes when the second entry for Sam hits the Return table (Return.ID 599) as the client's weekly reports are added to the table.  When that happens, the query appropriately (for my purposes) only lists that two of Sam's checks have been processed, but uses the "Top 1 ID" record to supply the row's details from the Return table:

```
Checks_Return_query:

Checks.ID Name    Acct    Amt    Our_Date      Their_Date    Return.ID
__        ____    ____    ____    _____        ______        ________
1         Dave   1001    10.51    2/14/14      3/25/14        355
2         Joe    1002    12.14    2/28/14      4/04/14        378
3         Sam    1003    50.00    3/01/14      3/08/14        433
4         Sam    1003    50.00    4/01/14      3/08/14        433
```

In other words, the query repeats the Return table info for record Return.ID 433 instead of matching Return.ID 599, which is I guess what I should expect from the TOP 1 operator.

So I am trying to figure out how I can get the query to take the two concatenated fields in Checks and Return, compare them to find matching sets, then select the next unmatched record in Checks (with "next" being measured either by the ID or Our_Date) with the next unmatched record in Return (again, with "next" being measured either by the ID or Their_Date).

I spent many hours in a dark room turning the query into various joins, and back again, looking at functions like WHERE NOT IN, WHERE NOT EXISTS, FIRST() NEXT() MIN() MAX().  I am afraid I am way over my head.

I am beginning to think that I may have a structural problem, and may need to write the "matched" records in this query to another table of completed transactions, so that I can differentiate between "matched" and "unmatched" records better.  But that still wouldn't help me if two of Sam's transactions are on the same weekly report I get from my client.

Are there any suggestions as to query functions I should look into for further research, or confirmation that I am barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you really need another table of completed transactions, it could be temporary table.

Regarding your fears *"... if two of Sam's transactions are on the same weekly report* ", you can use cursor in order to write records "one-by-one" instead of set based transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I think I will have to use a junction table, match what can be matched automatically, then make forms to allow a human to match the rest.  Sigh.  Much more work that I had hoped.